# Dictionary from json only printing first two items

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a json file that looks like this:

```json
[{"groupid": -1001742069667, 
  "5214840393": "0x8B9e9893663f1845304073f0250b8d706145ceF1", 
  "5214840393": "0x8B9e9893663f1845304073f0250b8d706145ceF1", 
  "5214840393": "0x8B9e9893663f1845304073f0250b8d706145ceF1"
  }, 
  {"groupid": -1001742069669}, 
  {"groupid": -1001742069669}, 
  {"groupid": -1001742069669}, 
  {"groupid": -1001742069669}]
```

when I try to print the first dictionary items with this code:

```
import json
file=open("addresses.json",'r')
new = json.load(file)
print(new[0])
```

it only shows this:

```
{'groupid': -1001742069667, '5214840393': '0x8B9e9893663f1845304073f0250b8d706145ceF1'}
```

while I expected it to print all items

Comment: there is 3 items not two in new [0]

Comment: You use the same key multiple times, so it's only giving you the last one.

Comment: Also there are 4 key value pairs, not 3 as your comment says.

Answer (score 1):

<s>`json.load(file)` returns a list of the items contained in the file. You can print all the items one by one like this:</s>

```py
for item in new:
  print(item)
```

By the way: You might want to use a context manager (keyword `with`) to handle the file. That way you can make sure that it is properly closed, which it currently is not. You would write something like this:

```py
import json
with open("addresses.json",'r') as file:
  new = json.load(file)

# file is properly closed upon leaving the "with" block

for item in new:
  print(item)
```

Comment: This is not really answering the question. The real issue is that in the original post, the first object in the list contains the same key more than once, therefore the dictionary only takes the last key with its value

Comment: Oh, wow, you are right. Totally misread the question, here.